# How to clean the scan data in Blender?

Tags: uv-image-editor

sorry, absolutely beginner here.

I need advice how to fix some problem areas in the texture of scanned model.
see the attachment.

Thank you.
Gregory
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blender has a texture painter tool that could fill in that area with a smooth color. If all the textures have their own UV islands, it is a simple fix. [image: texture painter view]

Comment: Thanks, I will try